# Sencha Touch 2 sass compiling time very long

Tags: sencha-touch, sass, compass-sass

I started working with SenchaTouch2 and currently trying to use SASS.

When compiling my .scss file (app.scss) which is generated by Sencha, it takes up to 10 seconds.

I now wonder if this is normal because to wait 10 seconds every time I change somthing seems to long when developing an application.

I would like to know if you experience similiar times when compiling your sencha .scss file(s).

I use the following versions for compiling:
Sass 3.3.0.alpha.121 (Bleeding Edge)
Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `compass watch` command for compilation, it's way faster.

And keep `compass clean` at hand, it helps when Compass cache gets out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that familiar with Sencha, but 10 seconds isn't very long to wait for a compilation. Some IDE's have a feature where only changed portions are re-compiled while things that have not changed are skipped. For Instance, Visual Studio calls these Build and Rebuild. This may or may not help you.

Comment: While I agree with you that 10 seconds isn't very long, I become used to the nearly instantly visualisation on my page when editing the css directly. 10 seconds without even adding my own code, would result in not using sass and just keep writing css directly.